# UnsatisfiedLinkError using `jargon2-native-ri-backend` library on Mac air M2

Tags: maven, javafx, maven-plugin, apple-m1

I'm having a problem running my JavaFX application on a MacBook Air with an M1 chip. When I try to launch my application, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1858)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1726)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3684)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3989)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2704)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)

    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.base@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:270)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1853)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/pd/n13rr22d0wd6c9wc7x0mcmz00000gn/T/jna-445275207/jna5093040430395823145.tmp: dlopen(/private/var/folders/pd/n13rr22d0wd6c9wc7x0mcmz00000gn/T/jna-445275207/jna5093040430395823145.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/pd/n13rr22d0wd6c9wc7x0mcmz00000gn/T/jna-445275207/jna5093040430395823145.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64,unknown', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/private/var/folders/pd/n13rr22d0wd6c9wc7x0mcmz00000gn/T/jna-445275207/jna5093040430395823145.tmp' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/pd/n13rr22d0wd6c9wc7x0mcmz00000gn/T/jna-445275207/jna5093040430395823145.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64,unknown', need 'arm64'))
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2404)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:817)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:2015)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:761)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:131)
    at com.sun.jna.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:41)
    at com.kosprov.jargon2.nativeri.backend.NativeRiJargon2Backend.copyToMemory(NativeRiJargon2Backend.java:274)
    at com.kosprov.jargon2.nativeri.backend.NativeRiJargon2Backend.rawHash(NativeRiJargon2Backend.java:77)
    at com.kosprov.jargon2.nativeri.backend.NativeRiJargon2Backend.encodedHash(NativeRiJargon2Backend.java:140)
    at jargon2.api@1.1.1/com.kosprov.jargon2.internal.Jargon2BackendAdapter.encodedHash(Jargon2BackendAdapter.java:33)
    at jargon2.api@1.1.1/com.kosprov.jargon2.internal.HasherImpl.encodedHash(HasherImpl.java:245)
    at sio.projet_helport/sio.projet_helport.ConnexionController.btnValiderConnexion(ConnexionController.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 34 more
```

The problem seems to be related to an architectural incompatibility between the native library I'm trying to load and the M1 chip in my MacBook Air. I'm using JavaFX 20.0.1 and my operating system is macOS. I'm really stuck, especially since when I try on Windows everything's fine.

Here is my pom file:

```xml
...
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>20.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>20.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.kosprov.jargon2</groupId>
        <artifactId>jargon2-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.kosprov.jargon2</groupId>
        <artifactId>jargon2-native-ri-backend</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

...

        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>20</source>
                <target>20</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>sio.projet_helport/sio.projet_helport.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                        <launcher>app</launcher>
                        <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                        <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                        <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                        <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                        <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's my controller class where I use the dependency to hash a password:

```
...

public void btnValiderConnexion(Event event) {

    byte[] password = txtPas.getText().getBytes();

    // Configure the hasher
    Hasher hasher = jargon2Hasher()
            .type(Type.ARGON2i) 
            .memoryCost(65536)  
            .timeCost(3)        
            .parallelism(1)     
            .saltLength(16)     
            .hashLength(16);    

    String encodedHash = hasher.password(password).encodedHash();

    System.out.printf("Hash: %s%n", encodedHash);

    Verifier verifier = jargon2Verifier();

    boolean matches = verifier.hash(encodedHash).password(password).verifyEncoded();
}
```

I've heard of Rosetta, but I'm not sure how useful it is in my case. Also, I'm having trouble activating it on IntelliJ.  I've tried to activate Rosetta, but I can't find the feature on the application information page in IntelliJ. I'm at a loss as to how to solve this problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOsTj.png) : Comparison image between Safari where I have the option to launch with Rosetta and IntelliJ.

Comment: The `jargon2-native-ri-binaries-generic` (pulled in through `jargon2-native-ri-backend`) doesn't provide an arm64 library (it provides darwin (presumably x86-64), linux-x86, linux-x86-64, win32-x86 and win32-x86-64). I'm not sure why you show a screenshot of IntelliJ, because that is not at issue here. At issue is when you run _your_ application, using an ARM64 version of Java. You either need to find if there is a ARM64 for this jargon2 library, or find an alternative library.

Comment: Also, given the last release was in 2018, and the maintainer of that library hasn't committed since then, you will probably have no other option than to try and find a different library.

Comment: I edited your title to reflect your issue and removed the javafx-8 tag as you are not using JavaFX 8.

Comment: On the Rosetta option -> [apple states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/about-the-rosetta-translation-environment) "If a binary includes both arm64 and x86_64 instructions, the user can tell the system to launch the app using Rosetta translation from the app’s Get Info window in the Finder."  Perhaps (surprisingly) Safari is such an application so it has that option, but your Idea version is probably built to only use the arm64 native libraries in the JDK.  So the Rosetta option isn't provided because Idea can run directly on arm64 without Rosetta translation.